# Strange, thin line between adjacent, skewed blocks with transparency

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with semi-transparent blocks. The main problem is in thin line between the "block" element and its pseudo element (before). This issue appears in every modern desktop browsers (Opera, Firefox, Chrome. Dont know about Safari, though).
Code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="block"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.block{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: skewX(-21deg);
}
.block:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Example on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Farmatique/xw877edw/

Even if I set background color opacity to 1, this issue still remains.

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Looks like aliasing caused by sub-pixel rendering.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what yours looks like. I can't see the line: http://i.imgur.com/eInvdxJ.png

Comment: What's the point of the `before` element? Why not just increase the width of the main block element by 100px? https://jsfiddle.net/xw877edw/1/

Comment: Looks to be caused by the 'content' setting of your :before styling. Remove that and readjust accordingly?

Comment: While it doesn't solve it completely, I've found `backface-visibility: hidden;` fixes it slightly

Comment: @Tom yes, you`re right - it doesnt appear if we have different colors, only if we use the same color

Comment: @APAD1 well, unfortunately in my case I have to use pseudo-element..

Comment: I can see the line (in firefox) even with two different colors.  I, too, would guess this is caused by css anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An even better solution...

The problem you are running into is due to the [anti-aliased](http://www.telacommunications.com/nutshell/pixelation.htm) edges of the skewed elements sitting next to one another. The browser is doing its best to draw smooth, angled edges with pixels, and it uses various, lighter, more transparent shades of the background color you have designated, to give the illusion of a smooth edge. The "line" you are seeing is the lighter, more transparent pixels, which are allowing the white background of the document beneath, to shine through.

Instead of assigning `background-color` for the `:before` pseudo element, assign a `right-border` to the `.block` class, like this:

```
    .block{
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      margin-left: 100px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      transform: skewX(-21deg);
      border-right-width: 100px;
      border-right-style: solid;
      border-right-color: transparent;
    }

    .block:before{
      content: 'I\'m in the pseudo element';
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 100%;
      width: 100px;
      height:200px;
    }
```

Since the border is part of the `.block` `div` element, there is no longer a gap between shapes, and your `:before` pseudo element will appear over the border area, as if it had its own background color.

No more line.

Comment: nice solution, Jacefarm!

Comment: @EugeneMarinitch If that answers your issue, would you mind accepting the answer?  Thank you.

Comment: sure! Sorry, I`m new to stackoverflow. Now I marked your answer as solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are running into is due to the [anti-aliased](http://www.telacommunications.com/nutshell/pixelation.htm) edges of the skewed elements. The browser is doing its best to draw smooth, angled edges with pixels, and it uses various, lighter, more transparent shades of the background color you have designated, to give the illusion of a smooth edge. The "line" you are seeing is the lighter, more transparent pixels, which are allowing the white background of the document beneath, to shine through.

From a CSS approach, you can try to fool the user's eye with a subtle `box-shadow` property on the `:before` to tone down the anti-aliased edge:

```
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
```

If needed, adjust the opacity to see if you can find a sweet spot that works.

Another idea might be to try a color other than white, as a background behind the skewed elements, to tone down what shines through.

However, the caveat here, is that every device will have its own representation of the colors selected for the background and shadow, and it will be more noticeable for some, and not so much for others.